# How to implement user-defined function from c in stan

Tags: c, lapack, stan

I am trying to use HMC to do MCMC sampling with a self-defined target function. I had my HMC code, but it doesn't work well. I recently knew "stan" which has a more powerful HMC model. So I want to implement my code with "stan".

I have already coded the target function as well as the derivative function in C. It involves for-loop, and functions needed for Cholesky decomposition and other linear algebras from Lapack. I really don't want to recode it in stan. Is there any way to use my functions directly? I would also appreciate it if anyone can give some clues about how to modify my code, or teach me how to modify "stan" code. The following is part of my code:

```
void get_V(double phi, double sigmasq, double k, double *neardist, 
double *neardistM, int *nearind, double *w, int n, int m, double *V){

double one = 1.0, var;
int i, j, dim ,info, int_one = 1;
double *u, *temp_neardistM;
char UPLO = 'L';
char SIDE = 'L', DIAG = 'N';
char TRANS = 'N', TRANS2 = 'T';

var = (double)(1/k) * sigmasq;

V[0] = var;

for (i = 1; i < n ; i++){
    if(i < m) {
        dim = i;
    }
    else {
        dim = m;
    }

    ...       

    // Cholesky decomposition of temp_neardistM
    info = -1;
    dpotrf_(&UPLO, &dim, temp_neardistM, &dim, &info);   
    if (info != 0) {free(temp_neardistM); return ;}

    ...

    // get Vi
    dtrsm_(&SIDE, &UPLO, &TRANS, &DIAG, &dim, &int_one, &one, temp_neardistM, &dim, u, &dim);
    V[i] = (var - sigmasq * (sq_sum(u, dim)) );

    ...

    }
}
```

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to interface Stan with C or Fortran because Stan relies on templated C++ to handle the autodifferentiation among other reasons. But if you can write C code, you can write code. The Stan language has `cholesky_decompose` and matrix solvers (with the `\` operator), so I'm not sure what else you would need to port a function like get_V.

Comment: I see, Thank you very much. By the way, do you know how to use user-defined derivative instead of the default derivative in "stan"?

Comment: That is not currently possible. But it usually does not matter that much since autodiffing only takes about 3 to 5 times as long as evaluating the posterior log-density.

Comment: Alright, I will try to rewrite it in "stan". Thank you.